# OpenLayers 3: get the osm_id of the closesd point

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers

Is there a way to get osm_id of the point that is closest to a given coordinate.

The idea is to click on map and get the osm_id

```
 map.on('click', function(event) {
      window.alert(event.coordinate);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can by using ol.source [getClosestFeatureToCoordindinate()](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getClosestFeatureToCoordinate) and feature [get()](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#get).

Assuming your OpenStreetMap data is loaded into [ol.source.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) called osm.

```
map.on('click', function(event) {
  var osm_id = osm.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(event.coordinate).get('osm_id');
  window.alert(osm_id);
)}
```

Comment: I think you have to elaborate a little bit. There's no `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate` for `ol.source.OSM`. How do you get `ol.source.Vector` with OSM?

Comment: I was working under the idea Alex was using something like this [OSM Vector Tiles](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/tile-vector.html)

Answer (score 2):

Returning objects at a given location is possible via [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Unfortunately I don't have a full example. But if nobody else comes up with an example I can at least provide you some helpful links:

- [How to build a custom POI map with OpenLayers and Overpass API](http://overpass-api.de/open_layers_mashup.html)
- [Various example applications using OpenLayers and Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Applications)

Comment: Overpass API can only return objects within a certain radius of a coordinate (or a way, etc.). If there's no result in the given proximity of a point (think middle of the ocean), you need to continue querying with a larger radius until you find something. Unfortunately, there's no other way atm to find the closest point for a given point.